# Is it possible to create a dynamic array of pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, dynamic

Basically I need to save a certain number of strings received from `stdin` in a dynamic list, but the number of strings is different for each node of my list. What I'm trying to do is to have a double pointer to `char`, so that I can have an array of strings (an array of pointers to `char`). But maybe it doesn't work this way.

Simplifying I have:

```
typedef struct table {
    int rowsNumber;
    char **array;
    struct content * next;
} content;

table* node=NULL;


int main() {
    ...
    nodecreate();
    ..
}
```

Then I need to create the table, but here is where I'm getting errors.

```
void nodecreate()
{
    char line[MAXLENGHT];
    scanf("%d", table->rowsNumber);
    for (i=0; i<rowsNumber, i++) {
        fgets(line, MAXLENGHT, stdin);
        node->array[i] = malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(node->array[i], line);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace the entire loop body with a simple invocation of `getline()`. It's standardized since POSIX.1-2008. The beauty of `getline()` is, that you sidesteps all the possible bugs that are associated with that fixed, finite, arbitrary `MAXLENGTH` value.

Comment: regarding: `table* node=NULL;`  This will not compiler, because the compiler doesn't know what a `table` is.  Suggest: `content  *node = NULL;` or `struct table *node = NULL;`

Comment: OT: regarding; `node->array[i] = malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.   2) when calling any of the heap allocation function: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%d",table->rowsNumber);`  The compiler has no idea what `table` is, so this line will not compile.  also, should always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Suggest: `if( scanf("%d", node->rowsNumber ) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of rows failed\n" );` // free all allocated memory then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `node->array[i] =`  the `char **array` field of the struct is never set to point to an array of `char *` so the data is being written to memory that the application does not own.  The result is undefined behavior (and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest, between: `scanf("%d", node->rowsNumber);` and `for (i=0; i<rowsNumber, i++) {` insert the lines; `node->array = calloc( rowsNumber, sizeof( char* ) ); if( ! node->array ) { perror( "calloc failed" ); // free all allocated memory then exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(line, MAXLENGHT, stdin);`  1) The function: `fgets()` also (if there is room) places the trailing newline into the buffer.  Usually you do not want that, so the next line should be: `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` to replace any (possible) newline with a NUL char.  2) the function: `fgets()` can fail, It returns a NULL when it fails, so the code should be checking for that.  Suggest: `if( ! fgets(line, MAXLENGHT, stdin) ) { perror( "fgets failed" ); // free all allocated memory then exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct table {
    int rowsNumber;
    char **array;
    struct content * next;
} content;`  There only needs to be a single instance of this struct.  The field `array` will have pointers to all the lines of data read from the user

Answer (score 0):

These declarations

```
typedef struct table {
    int rowsNumber;
    char **array;
    struct content * next;
} content;

table* node=NULL;
```

are incorrect.

For example in this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct table {
    int rowsNumber;
    char **array;
    struct content * next;
} content;
```

there are declared the type `struct table` its alias `content` and one more type `struct content`. The types `struct table` and `struct content` are two different types.

For this declaration

```
table* node=NULL;
```

the compiler shall issue a message that the name `table` is not declared.

It seems you mean the following

```
typedef struct table {
    int rowsNumber;
    char **array;
    struct table *next;
} content;

content *node = NULL;
```

In this function

```
void nodecreate()
{
char line[MAXLENGHT];
scanf("%d",table->rowsNumber);
for(i=0;i<rowsNumber,i++){
    fgets(line,MAXLENGHT,stdin);
    node->array[i]=malloc(strlen(line)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(node->array[i],line);
}
```

where a closing brace is absent there is used the null pointer node. So the function will at least invoke undefined behavior. The same problem exists with the data member `node->array` that has an indeterminate value.

To use the function `strcpy` you need to reserve also a character for the terminating zero character like

```
    node->array[i]=malloc(strlen(line)*sizeof(char) + 1);
```

Also pay attention to that after this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",table->rowsNumber);
```

the following first call of `fgets` will read an empty string (containing only the new line character `'\n'`) because the input buffer will contain the new line character `'\n'`. You have to remove it.

In any case the function does not make sense because the function as it is followed from its name `nodecreate` shall create a new node. So this means as the function does not have parameters that the function shall return a created node that can be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

malloc the array of pointers first.

```
//assuming you malloc'd the table somewhere before calling this...
void nodecreate()
{
char line[MAXLENGHT];
scanf("%d",table->rowsNumber);

node->array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*table->rowsNumber);
for(i=0;i<table->rowsNumber,i++){
    fgets(line,MAXLENGHT,stdin);
    node->array[i]=malloc(strlen(line)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(node->array[i],line);
}

//don't forget to free both every char * and the char ** somewhere...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant malloc array[i] if you havent already allocated some memory to array

You need to do 3 steps:

Step 1: Malloc the table node

```
node = (content*)malloc(sizeof(table));
node->rowsNumber = 5; // change to whatever you want
```

Step2:
Malloc the array of pointers:

```
node->array = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(node->rowsNumber));
```

Step3: Malloc individual strings in array

```
for(i=0;i<node->rowsNumber,i++){
    node->array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);// Change 8 to whatever size you want
}
```